# why it is not showing update value on button click from state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

could you please tell me how to get updated value from state.here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-ives-0t3yk

**my initial state**

```
const initialState = {
  userDetail: {}
};
```

I enter `10 digit` number on input field and press enter and update the user detail like this

```
const onSubmit = async values => {
    if (values.mobile.length === 10) {
      setUserDetail({ msdin: values.mobile });
      console.log(userDetail);
    }
  };
```

`setUserDetail({ msdin: values.mobile });` here I am updating my `userdetail` .

and try to `console the update value like this`

`console.log(userDetail);` .it is showing currently `undefined`.but expected output is `{msdin:'9999999999'}` (or whatever it is type in input field)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using hooks and it's not synchronised, it's async. Therefore, accessing the detail immediately after setting the value will not be possible. If you want to access the data there, you will have to use `values.mobile`

Comment: can you print after 3000 sec ...using setTimeout or use asyn await.I already tried but not working

Comment: it might be. But that is not a good way to do. You can try setTimeOut to try it. I think if your machine is fine, 500ms would be enough

Comment: @user944513 but is there a reason why you need to access it there directly?

Comment: because I want to pass this data from one component to another without props

Comment: from what I can see there, you are using the context to communicate the data around. So if you update the userDetail there to context, everywhere else that is using this context will get updated too. I don't see the `userDetail` being used anywhere in your code block

Comment: can you please explain with example ..!!please share with codesandbox link

Answer (score 0):

The state will keep the last value until the next render is called.

You can see this information on [react-hooks document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> During subsequent re-renders, the first value returned by useState will always be the most recent state after applying updates.

So, the code should look like:

```
  const onSubmit = async values => {
    if (values.mobile.length === 10) {
      const newUserDetailState = { msdin: values.mobile }
      setUserDetail(newUserDetailState);
      // do your stuffs with the newUserDetailState instead of userDetail
      console.log(newUserDetailState);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The state setter `setUserDetail` is async, that means that the new state value won't be available immediately.

To see if the state update use `useEffect` like this :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect -> UserDetail : ', userDetail);
  }, [userDetail]);
```